# i am trying to display last updated records from table using group by and order by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display last updated records from table using group by and order by but its showing first inserted value not last updated . I did tried but its not showing last updated value please try to solve this query .

Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock_maintenance` (
  `sid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prodid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `stock` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `stock_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;

INSERT INTO `stock_maintenance` (`sid`, `prodid`, `stock`, `stock_date`) VALUES
(2, 34, 133, '2014-11-02'),
(3, 34, 267, '2014-11-05'),
(5, 35, 12, '2014-11-02'),
(24, 35, 10, '2014-11-04'),
(26, 35, 167, '2014-11-05'),
(27, 34, 167, '2014-11-08'),
(28, 34, 163, '2014-11-16'),
(29, 35, 163, '2014-11-15');
```

my Sql Query

```
SELECT * FROM stock_maintenance group by prodid order by stock_date
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default sort order in MySQL is ASC (ascending), meaning lowest to highest. So your query is sorting from lowest (earliest) date to highest (latest) date.

So to get the most recent records first, you can change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM stock_maintenance group by prodid order by stock_date DESC
```

Update:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM stock_maintenance ORDER BY stock_date DESC)
    AS sm GROUP BY prodid
```

Comment: i tried but its showing only first inserted like for 34 prodid its showing 133 and for 35 prodid its showing 12 but i want 34 prodid 163 and 35 prodid 163

Comment: @Bhavesh I see what you mean. Edited post with a query that gives the desired result.

Comment: This solution relies on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the relevant page of the manual). Szymon Stepniak's solution *is* documented and, in general, slightly faster.

Comment: @Strawberry That's an excellent point. I've updated Szymon Stepniak's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `inner join` subquery:

```
SELECT sm.* 
FROM stock_maintenance sm 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT prodid, MAX(stock_date) AS stock_date
    FROM stock_maintenance GROUP BY prodid
) AS max USING (prodid, stock_date);
```

And the result is:

```
'28', '34', '163', '2014-11-16'
'29', '35', '163', '2014-11-15'
```

Comment: @bsy This is exactly as complicated as it needs to be.

Answer (score -1):

You can acheive this by running a sub-select query first to order the results and then group by .

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from stock_maintenance order by stock_date desc) as temp_table group by prodid order by stock_date ;

+-----+--------+-------+------------+
| sid | prodid | stock | stock_date |
+-----+--------+-------+------------+
|  29 |     35 |   163 | 2014-11-15 |
|  28 |     34 |   163 | 2014-11-16 |
+-----+--------+-------+------------+
```